# New version of WordPress plugin not reflected

Tags: wordpress, svn

I'm new to WordPress. I was trying to upload a new version of my plugin after a bug fix. In `trunk/readme.txt`, I've mentioned `Stable tag: 1.0.1`. Also added all the new code to folder `tags/1.0.1`.

But still, when I visit my plugin's home screen, it shows the version as 1.0.0. Also, in side a WordPress admin page of a site, it says that latest version(1.0.0) of my plugin is installed which is not true. It should be 1.0.1.

Plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/negotiabl-woocommerce-extension/

SVN : http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/negotiabl-woocommerce-extension/

What am I missing out? Please help me crack this

Answer (score 1):

In addition to changing the readme.txt file and tagging, you also need to change the version number in the header of the plugin's main file - `plugin.php` file in your case.